# Do companions in Fallout 4 collect items by their own choice?

Tags: fallout-4

[On this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/243883/is-there-any-scrappable-junk-i-should-hold-on-to-that-could-otherwise-be-used-fo/245118#245118) somebody said some companions will collect items on their own. Is that true (and, if so, which companions collect which items)?

Comment: I don't believe that is true, no.

Comment: actually I had nick collect a few weapons that I never gave him

Comment: I think they might pick up weapons and power armor in the middle of combat?

Answer (score 2):

Companions won't collect items for you unless you specifically tell them to loot an object.

Companions however do sometimes randomly give you "gifts" when talked to.

- Strong gives raw meat.
- Piper gives pre-war foods
- Hancock gives drugs
- Codsworth gives    water
- Curie gives stimpacks
- Cait gives booze
- others give ammo    related to the weapons    they use (X6 and Danse
  give    energy ammo    while McReady gives    ballistic ammo)

Only Preston and Dogmeat don't give anything as far as i know.

Comment: Actually had Nick collect some laser guns and ammo without telling him to. Also Nick doesn't give anything when talked to